# Call jqXHR.abort without triggering an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jqxhr

I have a jqXHR object which I get from a backbone collection:

```
var xhr = this.collection.fetch({
  error: function() { alert("oh noes!"); }
});
```

Sometimes I then need to call xhr.abort().  But this is also triggering the error callback.

How can I call xhr.abort() without triggering an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error function will always be called. But you can check if it was an abort in the error function and ignore it:

```
    var xhr = this.collection.fetch({
        error: function(model, jqXHR, options) {
               if (jqXHR.textStatus != "abort")
                  alert("oh no!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I I know this was a long time ago, but I found the attribute to be statusText, not textStatus.